# Gulp - copy folders except

Tags: gulp

I want to copy my **vendor** folders (and more) but without specific one's example  **`phpunit`**.

How can I do that?

**I tried this but doesn't work:**

```
return gulp.src(['!vendor/phpunit',  'config/**/*',
'public/**/*',  'src/**/*',  'vendor/**/*'], {"base": "."})
.pipe(gulp.dest(path));
```

Comment: Put the negation one last - that is how they are processed.

Comment: Not only have to give it as the last one but also `!vendor/phpunit/**/*`. Now it works. Thanks. Post an anwser so I mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp always performs the negations in gulp.src() last no matter the order they are listed.  See [glob negations performed last](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/837#issuecomment-68069722).  So you should reorder your gulp.src so that

> '!vendor/phpunit'

is last.  You real issue as you point out is that you need

> '!vendor/phpunit/**/*'

But the information about the glob negation order is not well-known and trips up a lot of people who aren't expecting it so I'll note it here.  In your case, simply making your change in the old order may have worked fine.